# Fell asleep with slow cooker on warm for 9 - 10 hours? Still good?

Tags: food-safety, crockpot

Making applesauce in slow cooker.  Was supposed to put it on 4.5 hrs on high but cooked it 4.5 hrs on low.  It then switched to warm and sat on warm for 8 hours.

I'm planning to turn it back on high for another 2 - 3 hrs.  Thoughts?  It should still be good right?  The only ingredients in the cooker are apples, cinnamon, cloves and nutmeg.

Comment: Oh I forgot to say - I fell asleep and it autoswitched to warm and when I woke up I realized what had happened.

Comment: Did you check the temperature when it was on warm?  Warm means something different to different models of slow cooker.  Without a temp reading no one can tell you if it is safe or not.

Comment: Odd are, unless your slow cooker is defective, 'warm' will keep it above 140°F.  Also, applesauce is high in sugar, which will help to keep down microbial activity.